# Logging @Controller Requests Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, logging, spring-boot

I am trying to log my `@Controller` request (both request name and data ) using spring `@Aspect` in spring boot .
The issue is that when using `@Valid` with no valid data the method is not execute since the argument resolving happened before.

I have also tried the following solutions ,but they didn't worked for me:

1. Implementing Filter - It required to cache the Stream and Implement your own Servlet Stream + It disable the abbility to use ThreadContext in order to identify the request in all logs in logic.
2. Interceptor - I was trying to add Interceptor this has two problems first extends WebMvcAutoConfiguration.EnableWebMvcConfiguration or WebMvcConfigurationSupport cause the Autoconfig not to work secondly in order to get the data I need to add it in a later phase since in pre handle it not readed yet .I can use ThreadContext and `@InitBinder` for that I guess but it still leave me with the first problem and very not clean solution.

If anyone has other idea or good suggestion on how to use @Aspect with @Valid it will be very helpful .
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to simply log the request? Also by that you mean to log any request params etc ?

Comment: You can just add the actuator from spring boot to get logging of requests. You can also add a `CommonsRequestLoggingFilter` to log all incoming requests. Using `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` is the wrong way to configure and interceptor you should use `WebConfigurerAdapter` instead.

Comment: I would like to log both request path and payload .

Comment: The actuator logs does not print the request json + i would like to use my own logger and inject the request to all logic logs.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get my aim using the following code.

```
@ControllerAdvice
@Component
public class ControllerLogger {

    @InitBinder
    private void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder,WebRequest webRequest) {
        //log the request and data here .
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To log request and response headers and body you can register your log filter:

```
package demo;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.DispatcherType;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper;
import org.apache.commons.io.output.TeeOutputStream;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.mock.web.DelegatingServletOutputStream;

@Configuration
public class HttpServerConfig {

    private final static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(HttpServerConfig.class.getName());

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean logFilterRegistration() {
        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registration.setDispatcherTypes(DispatcherType.REQUEST);
        registration.setFilter(new Filter() {
            @Override
            public void init(FilterConfig fc) throws ServletException {
                LOG.info("Init LOG Request Filter");
            }

            private void logRequest(HttpServletRequest httpReq) throws IOException {
                // log request headers
                LOG.info("### Request Headers:");
                for (String header : Collections.list(httpReq.getHeaderNames())) {
                    LOG.log(Level.INFO, "\t* {0}: {1}", new Object[]{header, httpReq.getHeader(header)});
                }
                // log request body
                Scanner qs = new Scanner(httpReq.getInputStream()).useDelimiter("\\A");
                String qb = qs.hasNext() ? qs.next() : "[empty body]";
                LOG.log(Level.INFO, "### Request body: `{0}` ###", qb);
            }

            private void logResponse(HttpServletResponse httpResp, ByteArrayOutputStream baos) {
                // log response headers
                LOG.log(Level.INFO, "### Response [{0}] Headers:", httpResp.getStatus());
                for (String header : httpResp.getHeaderNames()) {
                    LOG.log(Level.INFO, "\t* {0}: {1}", new Object[]{header, httpResp.getHeader(header)});
                }
                // log response body
                LOG.log(Level.INFO, "### Response body: `{0}` ###", baos.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
                logRequest((HttpServletRequest) req);

                HttpServletResponse httpResp = (HttpServletResponse) resp;
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                final PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(baos);
                chain.doFilter(req, new HttpServletResponseWrapper(httpResp) {
                    @Override
                    public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
                        return new DelegatingServletOutputStream(new TeeOutputStream(super.getOutputStream(), ps));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException {
                        return new PrintWriter(new DelegatingServletOutputStream(new TeeOutputStream(super.getOutputStream(), ps)));
                    }
                });
                logResponse(httpResp, baos);

            }

            @Override
            public void destroy() {
                LOG.info("Destroy LOG Request Filter");
            }
        });
        return registration;
    }
}
```